# Set button text Foreground on MouseOver

Tags: wpf, xaml

Trying to do some changes on `Button MouseOver`, the button `Background`, `BorderBrush`, are changing as expected, but not the `Foreground`.  I'm using a style, from a Resource Dictionary:

```
<Style x:Key="RoundedCorners" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ControlDefaultBackground}" />
    <!--<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ControlDefaultBorderBrush}" />-->
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border x:Name="border"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        CornerRadius="10">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                      Focusable="False"
                                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                      RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                      />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource ControlMouseOverBorderBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="Gray" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=BorderBrush}" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=BorderBrush}" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=BorderBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource ControlBrightDefaultBackground}" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource ControlBrightDefaultBorderBrush}" />
                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="Black" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

as per the posted suggestion below, I cannot get it to work outside of the `Windows.Resources`, nor can I get it to work in conjunction with the `ControlTemplate` styling (i.e., it is only working in the precise context of the answer).  My reading leads me to believe there is a hierarchy regarding the ControlTemplate, but I don't know enough about templating to understand it intuitively

When looking at the foreground colour in the debugger, it is set correctly, but does not display correctly.

I had a similar issue with a `DataGridHeader` Style, but by adding the `<ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>` the issue was fixed.  Unfortunately `Foreground` is not a recongnised part of the ContentPresenter so my fix for the buttons is not as simple.

````
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="SlateBlue"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Border Background="#FF2D2D2D">
                        <Border BorderThickness="1"
                            Background="SlateBlue"
                            Padding="10,0,0,0"
                            CornerRadius="0,10,0,0">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change foreground color of button in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40534966/how-to-change-foreground-color-of-button-in-wpf)

Comment: thanks, sadly nothing happens.  something is overwriting my desires but i have no other code referring to the buttons...

Comment: did you try that answer on a new project to avoid all side effects?

Comment: it works in a new project, but i need to add it to the existing style which i cannot get working

Comment: you should work this out step by step. add all style entries one by one and check after each if it is still working. at one point it should not work and you have the bad boy of your code. BTW that is very common way in programming to isolate a failure

Comment: the suggestion does not work

Comment: Well, as you told the suggestion works in a new project. So that general statement is not true. If it does not work in your project then there is something wrong with your code we do not have. Did you follow my last comment? Then you should have a minimal complete and compilabe code that you can post here instead of "it does not work" which does not tell anything.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestions, hence having tried them both directly and tried using them in context to understand my problem further.  I have edited the question with a compilable button style.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to this answer:  [Button's ControlTemplate's ContentPresenter's Textblock's Foreground not changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27115169/buttons-controltemplates-contentpresenters-textblocks-foreground-not-changin)

the `ContentPresenter` was using the `TextBlock` style, which was overriding the `Foreground` changes.  Adding this to the ContentPresenter fixed it by resetting the `TextBlock`

```
<ContentPresenter.Resources>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{x:Null}" />
</ContentPresenter.Resources>
```